# Hiding empty section of a custom content type if field is left empty

Tags: entities

I am relatively new to Drupal so I need someone to school me here.

I have created a custom theme and using theme key to attach it to a new content type (HTML Email). It roughly has about 12 sections consisting of a header graphic and a text area.

I’ve created a view and added all the fields to it displaying as a block in my custom theme using the views-view-fields—[name].tpl.php.

It displays perfectly but my issue is not all the section of the content type will be used so If the text area in a section is left blank I want that section not to show up in the block.

Below doesn't seem to work

```
<? if ($fields['field_text']->content): ?>
     <table border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <tr>
           <td><?php print $fields['field_header']->content; ?></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td valign="top" style="padding:5px 20px"><?php print $fields['field_text']->content; ?></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<? endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See also the Empty Field module:

https://drupal.org/project/empty_fields

This module can replace the markup of an empty field with some other output, which might be helpful in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you're testing for a string in $fields['field_text']->content and finding that even when it seems to be blank, it still prints the table.
You might try outputting the contents, like

```
var_dump($fields['field_text']->content);
```

Perhaps there is some "invisible" content, like

```
<p></p>
```

If that's the case, then you could strip that out before testing for the existence of a string in the variable.

```
$tmp_content = strip_tags($fields['field_text']->content,'<p>');
if($tmp_content):
// print table, etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you will check your html code for that field, then you will find that `<span class="field-content"></span>` code for your field. So, there is content in your field and your condition will not be validate.

You can hide the empty fields from your views by setting in admin of views as below.

- Go to Administration -> Structure -> Views.
- Edit your views.
- Click on specific field in your views under Field section.
- Checked `Hide if empty` check-box under NO RESULTS BEHAVIOR fieldset and save the views.

Or you can use `strips_tags` in your code to remove html tag from the content of the field.